# JQuery not finding td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I am very new to Javascript/jQuery, so please bear with me.

I have setup a JSFiddle here:   [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DkB9t/37/)

As you can see in the comments, several attempts to find the div in the next column are failing.

Code here:

```
<table>
<tr id="testtr">
    <td id="fail">
        <select class="part_number" id="part_select_from_blanks" name="part_number">
            <option value="">Select a Part</option>
            <option desc="Dr. Orion Dickinson" value="32">Alice Wyman</option>
            <option desc="Fabiola Harvey" value="31">Camryn Tillman</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td id="fail2">
        <div id="desc_from_blank2" class="testclass">test</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And Javascript here:

```
$('.part_number').change(function () {
    var sel = $("option:selected", this);
    var desc = sel.attr('desc');
    alert(desc);
    //alert($('.part_number option:selected').attr('desc'));

    // This one finds the div correctly
    alert($('#desc_from_blank2').attr('id'));

    // This one only finds the div if I remove the <table> from html
    alert($(this).next().attr('id'));

    // this one never finds the div
    alert($(this).next("div").attr('id'));

    // This one never finds the div
    alert($(this).next().find('.testclass').html());

    // This works when I delete <table> from html, but not with <table>
    $(this).next().html(desc);
    alert($(this).next().html());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert($(this).closest('td').next().find('.testclass').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like,

```
alert($(this).closest("td").next().find('.testclass').html());
```

Because `testclass` is in the other `td`. So you need to get the parent first, Then select the `next()` which will get the next `td`. Then you can find the div.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4062/)

Answer (score 0):

Won't this do it?

```
alert($('.testclass').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't correctly selecting the right element. You could do this instead (assuming you only have one select and `testclass` result field on each row:

```
alert(
    $(this)               // select
      .closest('tr')      // parent table row
      .find('.testclass') // search for the div with testclass class
      .html()             // get the HTML contents
      .trim()             // remove any unnecessary whitespace from either end
);
```

If you have more than one per row, you can do this:

```
$(this).closest('td').next().find('.testclass').html().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

`next()` finds the next sibling of the element.  http://api.jquery.com/next/

So when you are using `$(this)`, you are telling to search for elements that have the same parent as your `.testClass` element.  There are no elements matching what you are looking for there.  You need to move up the tree with `parent()` or `closest()` to find the elements that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to use the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to find the `td` that encloses the `select` element that fired the change event, then from there, use `next()` to get the second column. Like so:

```
var secondTd = $(this).closest('td').next();
```